# Laravel: I can see my data but can't get at it. It's just a query returning a string

Tags: laravel, collections

I'm trying to learn Laravel again having looked at it a few years and am now back and revisiting it.

The issue I have is, I have been following along with the Laracasts Twitter project and all is fine but i have tried to implement stuff on Twitter, not shown in the tutorial - namely, retweets and proper Twitter functionality, DM's work too. All is good and working but i have hit a snag on actually getting at some data.

Basically to keep things simple, i have a Tweets table and this handles the original tweet and the retweet, and this works fine, rightly or wrongly constructed. However when i try to get the author of the original tweet, it falls down. I can see what I am looking for in the dump and the author data is there, the username in this case, but this is not being returned from the Model. This incidentally works in tinker with no issues.

I also have a User (with tweets() function) and Tweets model (with a User function)

I get this error and the data is appearing to be there and I can see it, appearing to be string 'Mikedeveloper' but I can't get at it when i try to return to this to the view:
https://flareapp.io/share/xPQxBgm1

So I have:

My table:

[image]

Template:

```html
<!-- This isn't a retweet -->
@if(!$tweet['rt'] && !$tweet['tweet_id'])
    <h5 class="font-bold mb-4">
        <a href="{{$tweet->user->profile()}}">{{$tweet->user->name}}</a>
    </h5> 

<!-- This is a retweet -->
@else
    <h5 class="font-bold mb-4 bg-green-300 p-2 text-white rounded">
        <a href="{{$tweet->user->profile()}}">
            {{$tweet->user->username}} retweeted:
        </a> 
        <a href="{{route('profile',$tweet->getUserName($tweet))}}">
            {{$tweet->getUserName($tweet)}}
        </a>
        <i class="fa fa-retweet" style="font-size:24px"></i>
    </h5> 
@endif
```

Model:

```php
public function getUserName(Tweet $tweet)
{ 
    // Query table on the tweet_id and get the original tweet id and then query 
    // that row and get the 'user_id'
    $user_id = $this::where('tweet_id',$tweet->tweet_id)->get()
        ->pluck('user_id')[0];

    // Use the 'user_id' and get the username of the original tweet. 
    $username = User::find($user_id)['username'];

    ddd($username);
    return $username;
}
```

Update:

Using the relationships - I now have this and again, identical problem, dumps out in the model fine and works in tinker! If i dump in the model it shows the username as a string but when i try to render it, error:

```
        $this->find($this->tweet_id)
        ->user
        ->username;
```

Finally works as below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Eloquent returns objects, not arrays. 
So you need to access them with ->propertyName

```
public function getUserName()
{ 
    $user_id = $this->user_id;

    $username = User::find($user_id)->username;

    return $username; 
}
```

Also take a look at relationships and accessors.
Firstly relationships so you can attach a user to a Tweet.

```
class Tweet extends Model
{
   /**
   * Get the user record associated with the tweet.
    */
   public function user()
   {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User');
    }
}
```

Then you can do the following:

```
$tweet->user->username
```

You can also make an accessor instead of the getUserName() function.

```
/**
* Get the user's full name.
*
* @return string
*/
public function getUsernameAttribute()
{

    return $this->user->username;
}
```

Then you can access it like this.

```
$tweet->username
```

Comment: Yeah I have the relationships set up and working so a User can get all their tweets and Tweet relates to a user. I have used the same table for retweets that has the tweet in, only separated by an rt flag and a retweet id - this is the initial id of the tweet.

Comment: Try to use the relationships then :) It saves you a lot of work.

Comment: I would but the retweet and the tweet are in the same table. So, a retweet has the initial tweet id i use to look that user up, then i look that username up. As I said, the User->tweet and Tweets->user and follows, follow etc are all in and working

Comment: You can define a relationship Retweets as relationship with a where clause to limit by rt = true or 1. So you could still use the relationships. Don't forget to mark my answer as solved if it helped you :)

Comment: I have and the answer hasn't. As above, shows in model in a dump, and tinker but won't show in the template and just still errors.

Comment: $this->find($this->tweet_id)
            ->user
            ->username works in tinker and dumps fine but I cannot access the string with a function call from the template

Comment: The error that you link, isn't an error. It's a dump of your variable.
So remove the ddd() and post the actual error then.

Comment: I am sorry, here:https://flareapp.io/share/x7XxZ37a

Comment: If i change $this->tweet_id and just enter the INT 2, it works return $this::find($this->tweet_id)
            ->user
            ->username; The tweet_id is passed from the instance and shows the INT but won't work in the query. I used  getUsernameAttribute() as you suggested

Comment: Like I said in my answer, you just need $this->user->username
Not $this::find(tweet_id), $this is your Tweet class.

Comment: Yeah, I followed your advice and used migrate:fresh, and it works. Thank you very much for all your help and patience!